# Difference of consecutive rows skip two

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
      stkPx  strike     delta trade_date  expirDate      dte  cType  pBidPx  pAskPx    dA
2     86.91    76.0  0.893083 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.50    0.56 -0.16
3     86.91    77.0  0.877667 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.60    0.66 -0.16
4     86.91    78.0  0.859326 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.71    0.76 -0.20
5     86.91    79.0  0.838882 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.85    0.91 -0.21
```

I need to take the difference of two consecutive rows, store the result in a new column dA and store the result in the second of the two consecutive rows, sort of like this:

```
gb['dA'] = gb['pBidPx'] - gb['pAskPx'].shift(-1)
```

But clearly this doesn't work as look at the `dA` column above. I need it to look like this:

```
      stkPx  strike     delta trade_date  expirDate      dte  cType  pBidPx  pAskPx    dA
2     86.91    76.0  0.893083 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.50    0.56  N/A
3     86.91    77.0  0.877667 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.60    0.66  0.04  #.60 - .56
4     86.91    78.0  0.859326 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.71    0.76  .05 #.71 - .66 
5     86.91    79.0  0.838882 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.85    0.91  .09 # .85 - .76
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your solution. You wanted to write `gb['pAskPx'] - gb['pAskPx'].shift(1)`. Note `shift(1)`, not `shift(-1)`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Well, I want to sell the pBidPx at row 2, and buy the pAskPx of the previous row, store the result in row 2, all the way down

Comment: mozway in their solution explains that it is how shift works. In order to align askpx from row 1 with bidpx from row 2 you need to shift askpx one period up.

Answer (score 3):

You should `shift` positively, not negatively:

```
gb['dA'] = gb['pBidPx'] - gb['pAskPx'].shift()
```

Output:

```
   stkPx  strike     delta trade_date  expirDate      dte  cType  pBidPx  pAskPx    dA
2  86.91    76.0  0.893083 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.50    0.56   NaN
3  86.91    77.0  0.877667 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.60    0.66  0.04
4  86.91    78.0  0.859326 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.71    0.76  0.05
5  86.91    79.0  0.838882 2008-12-29 2009-01-17  0.05205      1    0.85    0.91  0.09
```